# Can't POST complex object to web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm newbie to web API. I'm trying to post an object of `Student{ID, Name, Age}` to this action method in the API controller:

```
public void PostStudent([FromBody]Student student) //I omitted FromBody attr but it doesn't help
{
    students.Add(student);
}
```

`students` is a `List<Student>`

In fiddler I send a POST request to the API in a JSON format like this:

```
{
    "ID": 454,
    "Name": "Tamara",
    "Age": 15
}
```

I'm specifying the Content-Type as application/json also.

but executing this request doesn't add the data?

**EDIT**

Student class:

```
public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the ApiController:

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student { ID=1, Name="Rami", Age=67},
        new Student { ID= 2, Name="Nermeen", Age=44 },
        new Student { ID= 3, Name="Ashraf", Age= 30}
    };
    public List<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        return students.ToList();
    }
    public Student GetOne(int id)
    {
        return students.Find(s => s.ID == id);
    }
    //[ResponseType(typeof(Student))]
    public void PostStudent(Student student)
    {
        students.Add(student);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your `Student` C# class look like? And if you put a breakpoint on your controller is it definitely hitting the breakpoint when you post to the controller?

Comment: `Student` is just a simple class of three properties as I mentioned (`ID`, `Name`, `Age`). I set a breackpoint (I didn't know I could do that with API and Fiddler, thanks!) the object has been received successfully, the flow goes to the `Add` method, but requesting GET doesn't show the new object, I'm adding the code for `Student` class and the GET action

Comment: Are you actually hitting the controller?  If not, then you need to verify that your object is correctly formatted.
I'd recommend changing your incoming type in PostStudent to 'dynamic'.  That way you can inspect what arrives and verify that it matches the format you think you're sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last comment:

Keep in mind that api controllers are recreated for each request, so the data is not persisted if you simply add it to a property on the controller. Have a look here for the request life cycle: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application

You could persist it by either creating a singleton class to hold your data, or by storing it in a database.

Comment: I thought of that too, but in this tutorial: https://youtu.be/GbKBcDX8DDQ?list=PL6n9fhu94yhW7yoUOGNOfHurUE6bpOO2b&t=383 he used the same approach

Comment: in his example the list is `static`, which I guess would allow the get to retrieve it from the same instance still assuming the request is from the same client.

Comment: It might work for this example, but in a real-world scenario you would persist the data in some sort of database. As with the example in the video there is no way to ensure the data is persisted in any meaningful and reliable way. If the application were to ever restart it's gone, if a new instance of the controller is created (by another client) it's gone etc.